# How can I style the black bar to have an equal padding from top and bottom of navigation bar elements

Tags: html, css, css-float, padding

[image: navbar screenshot]
I am having trouble removing that black gap while maintaining even padding around the links and search bar simultaneously.

I have tried to remove floats and use margin.  When I do this, the search bar wont occupy more space with max-width or width styling, 'Login' wont go to the right side with magin-right:0px;.

When using float, the black bar is acting all funky. If I remove padding all together from navbar the bar shrinks to fit searchbar (I understand float removes the element from flow). But then when I want to a simple 3 pixil padding around the search bar, the links wont shift downward.

How can solve this?

```
<style>          
.navbar a{
            padding: 20px;
            font-size: 20px;
            margin-top: 1px;
        }
    .navbar a:hover{
        background-color: #DEB82D;
        color: black;
    }
</style>

<div class="navbar" style="display:block; 
background-color: black;    
box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0px #FFDF00;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0px white;padding: 3px;">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <div style="display:inline-block;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="" onclick="toggleSideBar()">
        <i class="icon-menu"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
        <div style="display:inline-block;">
        <a href="/">
            Troother.tv</a></div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;">
    <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['displayname'])) {
        if ($logincheck($conn, 4)) {
            echo "<a id='upload' href='upload' class='upload' >Upload</a>";
        }
        echo "<a id='account' href='account'>Account</a>";
        echo "<a id='logout' href='logout'>Logout</a>";
        } else {
        echo "<a id='login' href='login'>Login</a>";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div style="margin: auto; max-width:40%;">
    <form action="browse.php" method="get" >
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" class="searchfield" style="     min-width: 100%;
        font-size: 20;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0,.3);
    color: white;
    border: 2px double #FFDF00;
    padding: 5px;">
    </form></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
padding: 10px 10px;
background-color: black;    
box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0px #FFDF00;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0px white;
}
.navbar a:hover{
    background-color: #DEB82D;
    color: black;
}
.navbar div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.wid30 {
    width: 25%;
}
.srch {
    width: 40%;
}
form {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="navbar" style="">
        <div class="wid30">
            <div style="display:inline-block;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="" onclick="toggleSideBar()">
            <i class="icon-menu"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;">
            <a href="/">
                Troother.tv</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="srch">
        <form action="browse.php" method="get" >
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" class="searchfield" style="     min-width: 100%;
            font-size: 20;
        border-radius: 15px;
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0,.3);
        color: white;
        border: 2px double #FFDF00;
        padding: 5px;">
        </form></div>
        
            <div class="wid30">
        <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['displayname'])) {
            if ($logincheck($conn, 4)) {
                echo "<a id='upload' href='upload' class='upload' >Upload</a>";
            }
            echo "<a id='account' href='account'>Account</a>";
            echo "<a id='logout' href='logout'>Logout</a>";
            } else {
            echo "<a id='login' href='login'>Login</a>";
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```